# while True issue in Python

Tags: python, loops, process, while-loop

I am monitoring a specific PID with python and trying to execute a function if this PID is not there anymore to bring it up again. The problem is that my loop seems to be working for 1,5 (yes, one and a half) loop and then breaks it self.

```
while True:
    print "[DEBUG] We are in the loop"
    query = "Select * from Win32_Process where ProcessId = " + str(monitorPID)
    if (GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery(query).count == 0):
        RunTheProgramAgain()
    print "[DEBUG] Current PID is %d - ProcNAME is %s" % (monitorPID, procName)
    time.sleep(5)
```

It will re-run the program with success, it will update program's PID as well but when the second loop takes place, it breaks for no reason, before the last debug print. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show what `RunTheProgramAgain()` and `ExecQuery()` do.

Comment: Are you missing another closing paren?  Also, agree with Will.  You need to show more of your code.

Comment: @JulienBernu my code is formatted, indentation is right.

Comment: I also agree with Will.  You need to provide more information.  There are many possibilities: perhaps one of the functions GetObject, ExecQuery, or RunTheProgramAgain is hanging or raising an exception.  Perhaps you are right that the program is just breaking for no reason, in which case we all need to give up software development and go into politics.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in try block, and see if any exception is getting thrown.

```
while True:
    try:
        print "[DEBUG] We are in the loop"
        if (GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where ProcessId = " + str(monitorPID)).count == 0):
            RunTheProgramAgain()
        print "[DEBUG] Current PID is %d - ProcNAME is %s" % (monitorPID, procName)
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        pass
```